# UIScrollView containing rotated UIImageView won't zoom

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm using a UIScrollView with multiple UIScrollViews as subview, each containing a UIImageView to display a picture.
The app itself only supports portrait orientation, but I do want the image views to rotate when the device is rotated (observing UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification).
Rotation of the image views is done with an animated `setTransform:` using both `CGAffineTransformScale` and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.
Zooming the image views is done by returning the image view from `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` for the scrollview containing the image view.

This is all working great, except for one thing: when the image view is rotated, I am no longer able to zoom. Debugging shows `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` is being called, but `scrollViewDidZoom:` is not.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this problem?

Comment: But you are able to zoom when it is in portrait? If you rotate to landscape, then back to portrait, are you able to zoom again?

Comment: Yes, I can zoom when in portrait, and yes I can zoom again when returning to portait.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Fixed it by applying the transformations to the UIScrollView (containing the UIImageView), instead of the UIImageView itself.</strike>

Just applying the transformations to the UIScrollView didn't work well enough. It would put the rotated image inside a smaller view and zooming did not use the available screen space.

I finally managed to fix this though, so here's how.

**Requirements**

- A horizontally scrolling list of full-screen pictures
- Rotating the device must *not* rotate the app, but *must* rotate the shown picture
- Must be able to zoom pictures, both when holding the device in portrait and landscape orientation

**How I implemented it**

One main UIScrollView with height equal to screen height, and width equal to screen width * picture count. Paging enabled.
This main UIScrollView contains a subview for each picture. Each subview looks like this:
UIScrollView > UIView > UIImageView

The UIScrollView has the size of the screen, and its origin.x property is 0 for the first subview, and increased with the screen width for each subsequent UIScrollView. The result is a main UIScrollView, with all the sub UIScrollViews next to eachother like this (without the spacing):

```
┌────────────────────┐
│┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐│
││ 1 ││ 2 ││ 3 ││ 4 ││
││   ││   ││   ││   ││
│└───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘│
└────────────────────┘
```

To fix the rotation problem, the UIImageView is no longer a direct subview from the UIScrollView, but is now embedded inside a container UIView.
The `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` method of the main UIScrollView delegate now returns the container UIView for the visible picture, so this container UIView will be used for zooming.
Rotation of the image views is still done with an animated `setTransform:` using both `CGAffineTransformScale` and `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`.

My guess that the implementation without the container UIView did not work, was because the UIImageView can no longer be transformed by the main UIScrollView, when there's already a transform applied to it.

Comment: Lovely solution, I was fiddling around with the same problem, came to the same conclusion that the transformation already applied on UIImageView for rotation would not go along well with the scale. Your solution worked well, though there is a small clipping issue coz the UIView does not know the effective bounds of UIImageView which would be rotated inside it, hence this would not increase the contentSize of the scroll view. Will have to calculate and manually increase the contentSize of scrollView, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for this - I had a similar issue but it's a tricky one to google for :)